# Replace multiple characters in a string using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to replace multiple occurrences of multiple characters in a string.Let's say I have a string which contains spaces and `/` characters. How can I replace both with `_`?

I know how to replace a single character with the `replace()` method as below:

```
var s = 'some+multi+word+string'.replace(/\+/g, ' ');
```

How can I update this to replace multiple characters?

Comment: What would you like to do when more than one of the characters are consecutive?

Answer (score 1):

To capture multiple consecutive characters use the `+` operator in the Regex. Also note that to capture spaces and slashes you can specify them in a character set, for example `[\s\/]`. Try this:

```js
var s = 'some  multi///word/string'.replace(/[\s\/]+/g, '_');

console.log(s);
```

Answer (score 1):

Define your characters inside a list `[]`

```js
const r = "abc def/ //g h".replace(/[ \/]/g, "_");
console.log(r)      // "abc_def____g_h"
```

To replace multiple, use the `+` quantifier (*one or more occurrences*)

```js
const r = "abc def/ //g h".replace(/[ \/]+/g, "_");
console.log(r)      // "abc_def_g_h"
```

To replace the exact sequence " `/`" (Space+ForwardSlash) with "`_`"

```js
const r = "abc /def /g /h".replace(/ \/+/g, "_");
console.log(r)  //  "abc_def_g_h"
```